# Cordova 3.0.0 - ChildBrowser not working

Tags: cordova, childbrowser

All the cited examples show this as the correct code:

```
window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage( "http://www.someurl.com" );
```

However, "window.plugins.childBrowser" is null, whilst this is not:

```
window.plugins.ChildBrowser
```

Unsurprising perhaps when one considers that this is the last code in childbrowser.js:

```
cordova.addConstructor(function () {
    if (!window.plugins) {
        window.plugins = {};
    }

    window.plugins.ChildBrowser = new ChildBrowser();
});
```

*(extra information about this under the line below)*

However, although the ChildBrowser property in this line has a value:

```
window.plugins.ChildBrowser.showWebPage( "http://www.someurl.com" );
```

It still doesn't do anything.

Huh?

ChildBrowser.showWebPage() looks like this btw:

```
ChildBrowser.prototype.showWebPage = function (url, options) {
    if (!options) {
        options = { showLocationBar: true };
    }

    cordova.exec(onEvent, onError, "ChildBrowser", "showWebPage", [url, options]);
};
```

*ps: Cordova 3.0.0, XCode 4.6.3, ChildBrowser 5.0.0. The official plugin page at https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/480 claims that ChildBrowser 5.0.0 is supported by Cordova 3.0.0*

---

Just to check that window.plugins ref, I ran this loop:

```
console.log( "loop starts..." );
for ( var propt in window.plugins ) {
    console.log( "propt " + propt );
}
console.log( "loop ends." );
```

And it produced this:

```
[Log] loop starts...
[Log] propt ChildBrowser
[Log] loop ends.
```

Answer (score 0):

The official Apache plugin is "InAppBrowser"

Syntax is: 'window.open'

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/blob/master/doc/index.md

Comment: Thank you Bryan, I will have a look. I had heard about both of these plugins, but I was led to understand that they were both supported. Is ChildBrowser deprecated or something? Basically, why choose InAppBrowser over ChildBrowser?